# Raster image resizing unexpectedly when uploaded to svg-edit

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-edit

This is quite a project-specific question, to do with my implementation of [svg-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/)..

I've implemented the updated 'ext-server_opensave.js' (from [this](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/issues/detail?id=739) issue) so that the user is able to upload raster images from their file system.

The code snippet I'm having an issue with from 'ext-server_opensave.js' is the following:

```
    function importImage(url) {
        var newImage = svgCanvas.addSvgElementFromJson({
            "element": "image",
            "attr": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 0,
                "height": 0,
                "id": svgCanvas.getNextId(),
                "style": "pointer-events:inherit"
            }
        });
        svgCanvas.clearSelection();
        svgCanvas.addToSelection([newImage]);
        svgCanvas.setImageURL(url);
    }
```

The width and height attributes don't work when setting them there, the other attributes do work. It's a weird bug - the first image upload uploads the file in its original size, then every subsequent image upload resizes to 48x48. If I set the width and height values in that method I pasted above, I see the image in those dimensions for a split second and then it resizes back to 48x48. Basically, there's some handler/method down the chain that is resizing the image after `svgCanvas.addSvgElementFromJson` and `svgCanvas.addToSelection`, and I can't figure out where, after hours of debugging the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild shot, but perhaps adding at line 128...

```
case 'import_img':
        svgCanvas.setGoodImage(str64);
        importImage(str64);
        break;
```

`setGoodImage()` sets the default image size when inserting new images. The 48x48 size you are seeing is the size of the SVG Edit's logo.